# What's the correct methodology to implement In App Purchase that unlocks existing functionality?

Tags: xcode, ios5, in-app-purchase

So I've built an iOS app (my first) and I want to distribute it for free. It's a content creation app, and my plan is to allow the user full access to record up to 5 records of content for the purpose of evaluation. If the user likes the app and wants to continue generating new content, he'll have to purchase an unlock via in-app-purchase.

I've looked at the documentation, and I'm going to use MKStoreKit to do this. I understand that I'm going to be creating a non-consumable, non-subscription product to sell.

So my problem is that while I can find lots of information on HOW to do the actual IAP, I can't find anything on where or how to track that it was purchased. That is, how do I go about ensuring the app is unlocked? Does it require a round trip to the AppStore servers on every app startup? If this is the case, I'm a bit concerned about it because network connectivity is not a guarantee.

Another possibility I've been thinking about is writing some kind of semaphore somewhere when unlock is purchased, whether it's a file or just modifying a setting in a .plist. This is certainly optimal from a user-experience point of view, but can it be easily hacked? If I write a file, can a user just take that file and distribute it to whomever?

Is there some standard mechanism or methodology that's typically employed here?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: The hackers will hack it no matter what, I wouldn't worry to much about that. Focus on making it simple and easy to maintain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do is check with the Apple servers if the content is unlocked. If so, I change some attribute in a .plist and check it to unlock the content.
There are two common approaches to achieve that: The first is to check only if the attribute is not set (or with a specific value) and the other, more secure but, im my opinion, not the best, is to have a point in your app that everytime it is executed the Apple servers are verified again.
What you need to have in mind is that if your application is hacked, you can't do anything, but there is a great number of users (most of them) that don't care about hacks and not even Jailbreaks... so forget it and apply the check when the app opens and only if it is not unlocked yet.

Comment: Ok - that's good advice. I'm not terribly worried about hacking, but I just wanted to check to see if there was a standard way of doing things. It sounds like I'm going to use the plist option. Thanks!